# how to display size attribue as dropdown?

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes

In product details page, value of size attribute is displayed like:

[image]

I want to display it as dropdown. Please help.

The below code is use to choose whether it should be a dropdown or a swatch:

```
<dd class="clearfix swatch-attr<?php if ($_attribute->decoratedIsLast) echo ' last'; ?>">
    <div class="input-box">
        <select name="super_attribute[<?php echo $_attribute->getAttributeId() ?>]" id="attribute<?php echo $_attribute->getAttributeId() ?>" class="required-entry super-attribute-select no-display swatch-select">
            <option><?php echo $this->__('Choose an Option...') ?></option>
        </select>
        <ul id="configurable_swatch_<?php echo $_attrCode ?>" class="configurable-swatch-list clearfix">
            <?php foreach ($_swatchArray->options as $_option): ?>
                <?php
                $_optionCode = Mage::helper('configurableswatches')->getHyphenatedString($_option->label);
                $_swatchUrl = Mage::helper('configurableswatches/productimg')->getSwatchUrl($_product, $_option->label, $_swatchInnerWidth, $_swatchInnerHeight, $_swatchType);
                $_hasImage = !empty($_swatchUrl);
                $_liClass = '';
                $_aClass = 'swatch-link swatch-link-' . $_attribute->getAttributeId();
                if ($_hasImage) {
                    $_liClass .= $_swatchType == 'media' ? ' is-media' : '';
                    $_aClass .= ' has-image';
                } elseif (strlen($_option->label) > 3) {
                    $_liClass .= ' wide-swatch';
                }
                ?>
                <li class="option-<?php echo $_optionCode; ?><?php echo $_liClass; ?>" id="option<?php echo $_option->id; ?>">
                    <a href="javascript:void(0)" name="<?php echo $_optionCode; ?>" id="swatch<?php echo $_option->id; ?>" class="<?php echo $_aClass ?>" title="<?php echo $_option->label; ?>"
                       style="height: <?php echo $_swatchOuterHeight ?>px; <?php if (!$_hasImage): ?>min-<?php endif; ?>width: <?php echo $_swatchOuterWidth ?>px;">
                <span class="swatch-label" style="height: <?php echo $_swatchInnerHeight ?>px; <?php if (!$_hasImage): ?>min-<?php endif; ?>width: <?php echo $_swatchInnerWidth ?>px; line-height: <?php echo $_swatchInnerHeight ?>px;">
                <?php if ($_hasImage): ?>
                    <img src="<?php echo $_swatchUrl; ?>" alt="<?php echo $_option->label; ?>" width="<?php echo $_swatchInnerWidth ?>" height="<?php echo $_swatchInnerHeight ?>" />
                <?php else: ?>
                    <?php echo $_option->label; ?>
                <?php endif; ?>
                 </span>
                        <span class="x">X</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </ul>


    </div>
</dd>
```

And the js required for this is :

```
setAttrData: function(attr, i) {
    var optionSelect = $('attribute' + attr.id);
    // Flags
    attr._f = {};
    // FIXME for Custom Option Support
    attr._f.isCustomOption = false;
    attr._f.isSwatch = optionSelect.hasClassName('swatch-select');
    // Elements
    attr._e = {
        optionSelect: optionSelect,
        attrLabel: this._u.getAttrLabelElement( attr.code ),
        selectedOption: false,
        _last: {
            selectedOption: false
        }
    };
    attr._e.optionSelect.attr = attr;
    if (attr._f.isSwatch) {
        attr._e.ul = $('configurable_swatch_' + attr.code);
    };
    return attr;
},
```

If I do some changes here it is affecting the color swatches also. I want only size attribute to be displayed as dropdown not the color. Please help.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about JS and not Magento.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can chose for swatches in admin for a attribute just remove the select from size attribute in admin.

[image]

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

You must have third party extension installed on your setup. In the default Magento attribute values by default coming in select box.

You will need to find out extension which is converting this values in button format. Or check system configuration for more settings.

Comment: Is it not just javascript and phtml work?

Comment: Extension might be using  its own js. If you don't want this functionality just disable the module

Comment: can you please specify the name of extension you are using for this as some of the extension have  facility to whether you want make changes to default select box or not.

Comment: @AshishMadankar  I have updated my question. am using the default coding not any extension.